# retrieve manager EMP ID for multiple users or oU's

Tags: powershell

I would like to get code for getting user info and managerempID for OU's (multiple users)

**foreach($ou in $OUsToSearch)
{
$XXXUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter "enabled -eq 'true'" -Properties * -SearchBase $ou
foreach($user in $XXXUsers)
{
need code here to get user details and manager empid in a single csv file
}**
**
please help @Santiago Squarzon

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the exact properties you're after I won't be sure if this will suit you as required.

```
$Table = @()

foreach ( $OU in $OUsToSearch ) {
    $XXXUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter "enabled -eq 'true'" -Properties * -SearchBase $ou
    
    foreach ( $User in $XXXUsers ) {
        $Table += [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Name" = $User.Name
            "Employee ID" = $User.empid
            "Cost Center" = $User.CostCenter
        }
    }
}

$Table | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Exported_Users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Adjust the part under the "`$Table += [PSCustomObject]@`" as required.

Comment: thank you for your reply, My main concern is to get the manager EMP ID in the above table along with user information. please assist

Comment: $table is throwing "empty" value when I use the same code @minkulai

Comment: Before I go deeper in it, did you try to callout `$Table` without the pipeline to export as CSV to see if would actually show anything? I use the same concept of script in my company and works just fine, you'd just need to make sure you're using the correct `$User.WhateverAttributeYouNeedToFind`. You mentioned the manager EMP ID, however before going there we need to be sure you can at least retried the users attributes before doing the managers. Because that requires a bit more of PS logic afterwards.